# Finding Table in Database

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In Microsoft SQL Server

I need to find in which database and server a column name and table name is located.

I know a table name, column name.

How to find that in which database that table and column are located?

Comment: Look at which database you're connected to with the query that works?

Comment: Which sql server are we talking about (MySQL, MSSQL, Oracle ...) ?

Comment: We'll need more details to give you the best advice, what are you looking at? Is there a piece of code, or are you looking at some kind of database browser?

Comment: Multiple servers/databases could have the same table and column name.  What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: In Microsoft SQL server

Comment: You could install Sql Search (a free tool) that allows you to search for strings. It returns all object where it is present http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/

Comment: How do you know the table and column name?

Comment: People, people, he doesn't even know the *server*. All these intraserver searching tools are nice but kind of useless.

Comment: Missed the server part.  Without knowing the server, you have to know a list of possible servers, and have access to a server with Linked Servers to all of those servers.  Then loop through all of them.  But seriously, how do you know the table and column name, but not the database or server?

Comment: @DaveJohnson I asked for clarification on that 42 minutes ago and got no response.  OP has been on since and responded to another question since I post the question.  Even if you find matching names how does that help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to loop through all the databases to do it:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#DBNames', 'U') IS NOT NULL
      DROP TABLE #DBNames

    Create Table #DBNames (
        DBName  varchar(256)
    )
    Insert  #DBNames
    Select  name
    From    sys.databases
    Where   owner_sid <> 1

    Declare @DBName nvarchar(256)
            ,@TableName nvarchar(256)
            ,@ColumnName nvarchar(256)
            ,@sql nvarchar(2000)

    Select  @TableName = 'YourTableName'
            ,@ColumnName = 'YourColumnName'

    Declare SearchForDBTable Cursor For
    Select  DBName
    From    #DBNames

    Open SearchForDBTable
    Fetch Next From SearchForDBTable Into @DBName

    While @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    Begin
        Set @sql = 'Select  @DBName DBName
                            ,t.name TableName
                            ,c.name ColumnName
                    From    sys.tables t
                    join    sys.columns c
                        on  t.object_id = c.object_id
                    Where   t.name = @TableName
                        And c.name = @ColumnName'
        exec sp_executesql  @sql
                            ,N'@DBName varchar(256), @TableName varchar(256), @ColumnName varchar(256)'
                            ,@DBName = @DBName
                            ,@TableName = @TableName
                            ,@ColumnName = @ColumnName

    Fetch Next From SearchForDBTable Into @DBName
    End

    Close SearchForDBTable
    Deallocate SearchForDBTable
```

Comment: This does it, but I recommend using the sp_msForEachDB, as that does all the database-cursor-looping work for you.

Comment: No cursor or loop necessary: just use sp_msforeachdb .

Comment: *shakes fist at Philip*

Comment: Sure, but it's "undocumented" and has its problems.

Comment: @DaveJohnson you are 100% correct sir. Gobs and gobs of SQL experts have done many tests showing this can miss entire databases and possibly lock you server. [DO NOT USE sp_msForEachDB](http://shaunjstuart.com/archive/2012/10/its-time-to-retire-sp_msforeachdb/)

Comment: True enough--but for quick ad hoc "where's my data" issues (as this one appears to be), it is adequate.

Comment: @Kyle: Huh? I did not say that sp_msForEachDB does no cursor work or looping, I said that it "...does all the database-cursor-looping work for you".

Comment: My original comment was posted right after yours, you just stole my thunder is all. No worries : )

Answer (score 2):

Specify Just Column Name

```
SELECT t.name AS table_name, SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS schema_name,
 c.name AS column_name
FROM sys.tables AS t
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID
WHERE c.name LIKE '%Column_Name%'
ORDER BY schema_name, table_name;
```

Answer (score 2):

In SqlServer this query return a row if exist the table and the column

```
select * from sysobjects T
JOIN syscolumns C ON T.id = C.id
where c.name = 'COLUMNNAME' and t.name = 'TABLENAME'
```

Comment: The user doesn't know what database it's in, so which sysobjects?

Comment: @KyleHale As stated the user does not even know which server.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to do it. Start with a query to detemine if the tabe.column is present in the currently "selected" database:

```
SELECT db_name()
 from sys.tables ta
  inner join sys.columns co
   on co.object_id = ta.object_id
 where ta.name = 'Users'
  and co.name = 'CreatedOn'
```

Turn it into a routine that only generates results if it is found:

```
IF exists (select 1
            from sys.tables ta
             inner join sys.columns co
              on co.object_id = ta.object_id
            where ta.name = 'Users'
             and co.name = 'CreatedOn')
    PRINT db_name()
```

Then plug that into the undocumented yet insanely useful system procedures `sp_msForEachDB`:

```
EXECUTE sp_msForEachDB '
USE ?  --  Change context to "this" database

IF exists (select 1
            from sys.tables ta
             inner join sys.columns co
              on co.object_id = ta.object_id
            where ta.name = ''Users''
             and co.name = ''CreatedOn'')
    PRINT db_name()
'
```

This will print out the name of every database on the instance containing this table and column.

Comment: Be very [careful](http://shaunjstuart.com/archive/2012/10/its-time-to-retire-sp_msforeachdb/) when using msForEachDB.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way to do this using the INFORMATION_SCHEMA. You can expand upon what is in the select statement but the bare bones are as follows. I've been using a script similar to this since SQL Server 2005 and this was written just now using SQL Server 2012.

```
DECLARE @somecolumn VARCHAR(155) = 'name'

SELECT t.TABLE_CATALOG, t.TABLE_NAME, c.Column_name, c.ORDINAL_Position
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
ON t.TABLE_NAME = c.TABLE_NAME AND c.COLUMN_NAME = @somecolumn
WHERE t.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
```